# Pending transactions got cancelled after wating enough time or they keep pending forever?

Tags: transactions, metamask, etherscan, pending-transactions

There are solutions out there to cancel a pending transaction, for example sending another transaction with the same nonce to substitute it.

Also paying more gas to accelerate it or even pay to cancel.

Well, assuming non of this methods have worked, because they hasn't, and I still have the pending transaction there, my question is simple:

If I leave the transaction there forever, the day will come that it will dissapear, or it is going to be in pending forever?

It's important because I can't do more transactions with that account without removing that pending transaction. Since no solution has worked for me I wonder if patiente will be enough.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each node decides how many pending transaction it wants to keep.

If there are many pending transactions circulating in the mempools, nodes will start deleting lower gas price and old transactions.

As long as at least one miner node is keeping your transaction, you have a chance that it will be mined eventually. However, there is no certain way to know if that is the case. When in doubt, it is better to replace your transaction with another one with a higher gas price (gas price at least 10% higher, with the same nonce).

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Undead8 I have tried that already, it seems not to work adding a new transaction in the same nonce. I also raised the gas price by 10% and it simply don't change. Actually what I want is that node deletes the pending transaction finally. How much you think it could still be there, in how much time I should expect it to be finally deleted?

Comment: There is no way to know and it may never be deleted. Replacement transactions do work, so try to find what's the issue with yours.

Comment: Thanks @Undead8 and since it could hang there forever I tried to solve it, and succeed. For some reason I wasn't able to substitute the nonce via Metamask but I workaround replacing it via MyEtherWallet using offline mode. Since offline mode is no longer available in the current version I didn't from version 5 and it worked fine, I was finally able to replace the transaction.